# Home Heater Ignition Failure

Tags: electrical, hvac, repair

My house’s heater uses a hot surface ignitor. The ignitor won’t come on. All I hear is the motor running and no attempt at ignition. A professional checked it out and said electronics are good. This has happened to me three times, 2x in the past 30 days. He came the first and second time, not this last time. What could be the issue? Could it be the hot surface ignitor, or the flame sensor?[image: Heater][image][![enter image description here][image][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OunZ.jpg)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OunZ.jpg)

Comment: what did the professional do to repair it the first 2 visits?

Comment: Can you measure 120V at the HSI terminals on the furnace control board? Can you post photos of the furnace's wiring diagram, or at least its make/model info?

Comment: @ojait he couldn’t find any faults. In fact, it just started out of nowhere while he was here

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel unfortunately, there seems to be no branding anywhere on the unit. I’ll post pictures.

Comment: @MoAkashi is there a wiring diagram on the inside of the door...?  Also, can you get us a close-up of the ETL listing label in the lower compartment that clearly shows the whole label?

Comment: did you test the resistance of the ignitor?

Comment: Hot surface igniters are notorious for cracking. Any flexing of the igniter can crack a used one. A fingerprint on the surface will cause them to overheat and fail. If you get them on line and they are not shipped in a rigid container they come damaged more often than in good condition. I order multiples when I get low and when they come in I test them with a high end meter (in the package) if they don’t ohm out properly I return them. 
I have seen these igniters last 12-15 years and have also seen them last less than a month. If the electronics are good that is usually the failure point.

Comment: @EdBeal gotcha, I’ll give it a try

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel no diagram, but I’ll add more pictures

Comment: Can you pull that inner cover off and check the LED on the control board for a flashcode please? [Have a manual](https://www.questargas.com/ForEmployees/qgcOperationsTraining/Furnaces/Goodman_GMP_GMPE.pdf), BTW